# Why does my dax filter show empty values that are not in the filter instead of hiding them?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to filter values from a Column chart :

The chart is like this :

[image]

The lightgreen column chart value is from a Measure : `Selection Date`

And I use a Slicer to filter values like this :

[image]

The values are from a table `Parametres`

[image]

So here is my `Selection_Date` measure :

```
Selection Date = [DateFilter]
```

`DateFilter` is an other measure that choose how to filter the values (based on the slicer's selection).

```
DateFilter = 

var _today  = TODAY()
var _month  = MONTH(_today)
var _year   = YEAR(_today)
var _last_30_days = _today - 30 

return SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Parametres[Selection_date]),
        "Last30Days", CALCULATE( SUM(v_revenues[qty]), FILTER(v_dates, v_dates[Date] > _last_30_days )),
        "MonthToDate", CALCULATE(SUM(v_revenues[qty]), FILTER(v_dates, v_dates[actual_month] = 1)),
        "YearToDate", CALCULATE(SUM(v_revenues[qty]), FILTER(v_dates, v_dates[actual_year] = 1))
        )
```

This measure works but I still have one problem. The filter is ok but when I filter a values (example month to date) all the value that are not in the selection (all the values that are not november 2021) are still visible but they are empty :

[image]

[image]

So here is my question :

How can I add the values that are not in the selection ? How can I filter so it only display the values that are in the checked in the slicer ?

Per example, for Date to Month I want only this to be displayed :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using a Bookmark and then I associated a button to this Bookmark !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).